# Angularjs storing $scope variable

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, mean-stack

I'm building a web app using Yeoman Angular-fullstack. I'm confused about how to update my $scope variables so that once a change is made, the results are automatically displayed on the html page without a refresh.

HTML

```
<h1 class="page-header">Drugs:</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
        <div ng-repeat="current in alldrugs">
                <p>
                <a href="/edit={{current._id}}"> <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">{{current.name}}</button></a>
                <a ng-click="delete(current)"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button">delete</button></a>
              </p>   
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Controller.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('firstApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.alldrugs = [];

    $http.get('/api/drugs').success(function(alldrugs) {
      $scope.alldrugs = alldrugs;
    });

    $scope.delete = function(thing) {
      $http.delete('/api/drugs/' + thing._id);
      $http.get('/api/drugs').success(function(alldrugs) {
        $scope.alldrugs = alldrugs;
      });
    };
  });
```

When $scope.delete is called, the item is deleted, however the page does not reflect the changes until I refresh the page. I'm thinking it has to do with the scope of the http callback function. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: you can use `splice` but your backend should be updating the list. not sure if there is error on backend. try chaining your `delete` and `get`

Comment: At least put $http.get('/api/drugs') in the delete callback, on the safe side.

Comment: The code is almost straight from [the github project](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack), so I'm pretty sure it has to do with front end. Unfortunately chaining the delete and get didn't help. What's odd is that it's deleting successfully - the item gets updated immediately in the db and I can print the changes out in console. Nothing reflected in the html though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is both the $http.delete and $http.get is called asynchronously.

When the $http.get is called, the $http.delete hasn't been finished yet. You have to ensure that the get is called AFTER the delete.

This code will work, although it is not an elegant solution:

```
$scope.delete = function(thing) {
  $http.delete('/api/drugs/' + thing._id).success(function(){
        //The get will be called AFTER the delete
        $http.get('/api/drugs').success(function(alldrugs) {
           $scope.alldrugs = alldrugs;
        });
  });
};
```

Comment: This code worked correctly. Do you think nesting this functions like this would affect performance? The deletes aren't as fast as I would like them to be, but maybe that's just the nature of using ng-repeat. Thanks so much!

Comment: Well from the UI you cannot do better but it is too bad to do two queries to the server, the performances would be better if the delete would return you `alldrugs` so you don't need to query it again.

Comment: @TroyGriffiths: The problem with nesting functions isn't performance, but the readability of the code (It's called "callback hell", just imagine that you have 5,6 functions nesting). You can google "angular js promise chaining" to learn more about how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve it using only one request:

```
 $scope.delete = function(thing) {
  $http.delete('/api/drugs/' + thing._id).success(function(){
      $scope.alldrugs = $scope.alldrugs.filter(function(t) {
          return t._id !== thing._id; // Remove the drug which was deleted 
      });
  })
  .error(function() {
       // Drug couldnt be deleted, notify the user?
  });
};
```